# select row from table and substitute a field with one from another column if it exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join, substitution

I'm trying construct a PostgreSQL query that does the following but so far my efforts have been in vain.

**Problem:**
There are two tables: A and B. I'd like to select all columns from table A (having columns: id, name, description) and substitute the "A.name" column with the value of the column "B.title" from table B (having columns: id, table_A_id title, langcode) where B.table_A_id is 5 and B.langcode is "nl" (if there are any rows).

My attempts:

```
SELECT A.name,
 case when exists(select title from B where table_A_id = 5 and langcode= 'nl')
 then B.title
 else A.name
END
FROM A, B
WHERE A.id = 5 and B.table_A_id = 5 and B.langcode = 'nl'

-- second try:
SELECT COALESCE(B.title, A.name) as name
from A, B
where A.id = 5 and B.table_A_id = 5 and exists(select title from B where table_A_id = 5 and langcode= 'nl')
```

I've tried using a CASE and COALESCE() but failed due to my inexperience with both concepts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not very clear. "if not null" you say in the title. But the word "null" does not appear in the explanation. You mean, "if there is a related row in the  other table" ? "B.table_A_id is 5" : this is really a constant or refers to the corresponding A.id value ? An example would help

Comment: Do you only want to sub the "B.title" if "A.name" is null?

Comment: I've edited the title and added an example. Sorry for the confusion. B.table_A_id corresponds A.id indeed. And as for the substitution, A.name should be replaced with B.title if B.title exists with the above WHERE conditions.

Comment: What if there are two records in table B ?

Comment: There will be always maximum one row for the WHERE condition mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

araqnid's is the answer you are looking for, I bet.

But if you want to enforce that no more than one row is returned for each original matching `A` row, you might prefer to do a subselect instead of a LEFT JOIN. For example:

```
SELECT A.id, COALESCE(
  ( SELECT max(B.title) FROM B WHERE
    langcode = 'nl' AND B.table_a_id = A.id), A.name ) as name
FROM  A
WHERE A.id = 5
```

I use "*max*" here to select an arbitrary value, in the event there is more than one. You can use "*min*" or whatever you consider appropiate in your case.

Perhaps this is more easy to understand than the LEFT JOIN, but (apart from the two being not exactly equivalent) a JOIN will perform better than N subselects (much better is N is large).

Anyway, from a learning point of view, it's good to understand both.

Comment: This does exactly what I want. It substitutes A.name with B.title if the second exists, otherwise it uses A.name as return value from the COALESCE function. The B table will always only have 1 row for the given WHERE condition but I wonder why you used MAX() (or MIN()) instead of LIMIT 1. Also, just out of curiosity, is there a way to replace the name column with the value from the COALESCE() function? I use A.* to get all the values from table A and alias the result from COALESCE() as name and it adds an additional column name1 in the returned array. Thanks again.

Comment: You can perfectly use `LIMIT 1`  (it's just a little more Postgresql-centric than MAX/MIN). I added an alias ("name"). I'm afraid that you'll have to replace your `A.*` with the full columns list (except `name`). Anyway, using `A.*` is considered bad practice, usually.

Answer (score 3):

```
select A.id, coalesce(B.title, A.name)
from TableA AS A
     left join (select table_a_id, title from TableB where langcode = 'nl') AS B
       on B.table_a_id = A.id
WHERE A.id = 5
```

Comment: This is what you want, I guess. The only caveat is that this can potentially give more that one row per TableA row, if there are more than one TableB row that matches.

Comment: This also doesn't behave as wanted. It returns A.name every time, regardless of whether B.title exists or not.

Comment: +1 This should work and, in general, is better than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm not sure how your tables have to be joined, but something like this should do the job:

```
SELECT            yourcolumnlist,
                  CASE WHEN A.name IS NULL THEN B.title ELSE A.name END
FROM              TableA AS A
INNER JOIN        TableB AS B
ON                A.id = B.table_A_id
WHERE             B.table_A_id = 5
AND               B.langcode = 'nl'
```

Another way to do it would be to use the COALESCE() function:

```
SELECT            yourcolumnlist,
                  COALESCE(A.name, B.title)
FROM              TableA AS A
INNER JOIN        TableB AS B
ON                A.id = B.table_A_id
WHERE             B.table_A_id = 5
AND               B.langcode = 'nl'
```

Comment: Both queries return no rows. I have to point out that when table B doesn't have rows where langcode = 'nl', it should still return all rows from table A. And if there are rows where langcode = 'nl' then the field should be substituted as mentioned in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select A.id,B.title,A.description from TableA as A inner join tableB as B
on A.id=B.id where B.table_A_id = 5 and B.langcode ='nl'
```

Comment: This query won't return A.name when B.title is non-existing.